# How to add setup fee to Paypal subscription purchase

Tags: paypal-subscriptions

I do see that I can create a plan and subscription button within my Paypal account that can include a one time setup fee plus monthly fees, and I so see advice for using payment services like Stripe to do the same.

But I need to add a setup fee that posts to https://paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr/ using a standard web form submitting to PAYPAL like:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">  
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="YXZABCSAMGS"> 
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions"> 
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD"> 
<input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2">
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1"> 
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1"> 
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="1">
<!-- Set the subscription. --> 
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Product Name : Plan"> 
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="123456">
<input type="hidden" name="a3" value="20.00"> 
<input type="hidden" name="p3" value="1"> 
<input type="hidden" name="t3" value="M"> 
<!-- Set recurring payments until canceled. --> 
<input type="hidden" name="src" value="1"> 
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Subscribe"> 
</form>
```

I am hoping that there may be a variable like "setup_fee" that I can add here.

```
<input type="hidden" name="setup_fee" value="10.00">
```

However I tried that and it didn't work. Current docs give no clue but I am hoping that they may be outdated and such a variable is now available.

Does such a thing exist?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it should be directed to PayPal.

Comment: It was sked of Paypal support who had no clue. There is nothing in their docs about this. So I posted here in the hope that someone here may have some real experience without relying on docs that may be outdated. And you want to kill that?